# Splitting date regex

Tags: regex, pipe, yahoo

Hi I'm trying to split the format of the date YYYY-MM-DD to seperate variables in yahoo pipes.

I can get the regex working for the year but I'm struggling with getting the month and day.

My regex for year:

```
(?<=\d{4}).*
```

Yahoo pipes uses the replace regex I think, so I would need to select the year-(skip)-day to get the month. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The regex `(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})` matches and captures the elements of the date. I'm not sure how you'd use this in Yahoo Pipes, since I've never used it myself, but the regex should help you there.

Comment: I need to create a seperate regex rule for each variable so (?<=\d{4}).* regex for year will get the year from the date and store it in year variable.

Comment: So you want to match everything besides the month?

Comment: Yes, everything besides the month

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=\-).*(?=\-)` matches the month only.